# Not able to get input field at the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field in my JSP page and want it to be at the center of the screen but even after trying various methods its not happening . The div containing the input looks like this

```html
<div class="text-center" id="keywordSelect">
    <div class="text-center">
        <p style='text-align:center'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="name" placeholder="Enter Keyword" style='width:30em;display:block'>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="keyword_button">View</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `<center> .... </center>` tag to bring everything in center of your page :)

Answer (score 3):

Try This code.it will display your field at center of screen.

```
<div class="text-center" id="keywordSelect" align="center">
        <div class="text-center">
            <p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="name"
                    placeholder="Enter Keyword" style='width: 30em; display: block'>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="keyword_button">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `margin:0 auto`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="name"
                    placeholder="Enter Keyword" style='width: 30em; display: block; margin:0 auto;'>
```